# How to use Fable output to other JS projects

Tags: fable-f#

I have a small fs file code

```
module FableApp

open Fable.Import.Browser
let sum x y= 
    x+y 


let myfunct=
    let result=sum 5 10
    console.log(result)
```

I am trying to compile it to JS and use in other projects. I have seen that its possible through [Fable Repl](http://fable.io/repl/) but I want to do pragmatically. As I need to compile FsProjects in future.

When I tried to compile this using webpack then I got this code

```
(window.webpackJsonp= window.webpackJsonp|| []).push([
    [0],
    [function(n, o, t) {
        "use strict";

        function c(n, o) {
            return n + o | 0
        }
        t.r(o), t.d(o, "Sum", function() {
            return c
        }), t.d(o, "myfunct", function() {
            return r
        });
        var r = function() {
            var n = 0 | c(5, 10);
            console.log(n)
        }()
    }]
]);
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you try to accomplish. Do you mean that you want to have all the F# files compiled to single JS files without using Webpack?

Comment: no I want them compiled to corresponding JS files.

Comment: So if you have a project with the files 'Module1.fs, Module2.fs, Module3.fs' you'd like to have the corresponding output files 'Module1.js, Module2.js, Module3.js', do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirements I think that the [fable-splitter](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/tree/master/src/js/fable-splitter) npm package would be exactly the thing you are looking for.

As described in the documentation you would add a line to the `scripts` block of your `package.json` file in which you tell the script runner to build your project and put the unbundled files to the output location.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "fable-splitter src/MyProject.fsproj --outDir out"
}
```

There are more fine grained configuration options I'd suggest you look at the documentation to get acquainted with the API in case you should need it. If you want to use the configuration in your build you would change the script block to include a configuration parameter pointing to the config file.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "fable-splitter --config splitter.config.js"
}
```